# jQuery Drop Captions Plugin

Tags: jquery

i am trying to implement html in this jquery plugin [jQuery Drop Captions Plugin](http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/10/23/jquery-drop-captions-plugin-released/)
So i can customize the caption text, by default it takes just the title attribute, but instead i want to take the text from the details div and insert it in the caption, its there any chance for this ? thank you!

```
<pre>
<img alt="image" title="In ac lectus sit amet lacus suscipit commodo non in nunc!      Phasellus vitae arcu dolor, non luctus felis. 
    Quisque ut mauris eget massa lobortis venenatis et at nibh." src="img1.jpg"    width="300" height="199" class="right blacksheep" />
    <div class="details">
        <div class="bigCaption bookreg">Margiela Lookbook<br>
                    S/S 2012</div>
        <div class="buttonCaption mediumreg">Publication digitale</div>
    </div>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, in dropcaptions.js replace the line 33:

```
var caption = jQuery(obj).attr('title');
```

with:

```
var caption = jQuery(obj).next().html();
```

this will take the text from the adjacent div (as in your posted example)